# Регулярное выражение для получения текста с HTML страницы среди разных тегов

Tags: java

Помогите написать регвыр для получения названия городов со страниц:

```
<a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/zhanatas">Жанатас</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_7" title="+7° по Цельсию">+7</span><a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/zhangala">Жангала</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_10" title="+10° по Цельсию">+10</span><a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/dzhanybek">Жанибек</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_6" title="+6° по Цельсию">+6</span><a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/zhansugurov">Жансугуров</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_5" title="+5° по Цельсию">+5</span><a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/zharkent">Жаркент</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_3" title="+3° по Цельсию">+3</span><a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/zhezdy">Жезды</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_5" title="+5° по Цельсию">+5</span><a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/zhezkazgan">Жезказган</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_0" title="+0° по Цельсию">0</span><a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/zhezkent">Жезкент</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_-1" title="-1° по Цельсию">−1</span><a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/zhelezinka">Железинка</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_5" title="+5° по Цельсию">+5</span><a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/zhem">Жем</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_11" title="+11° по Цельсию">+11</span><a class="link place-list__item-name" href="/pogoda/zheltysuy">Жетысай</a></li></ul><ul class="place-list"><li class="place-list__item"><span class="place-list__item-temp t t_c_-2" title="-2° по Цельсию">−2</span>
```

Comment: [Не надо](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5045688) парсить html регулярками. Возьмите какой-нибудь html-парсер.

Comment: код вставлен идеально)

Answer (score 1):

Как предложили выше в комментарии - действительно лучше взять какой-нибудь html-парсер. HTML по своей природе не регулярен, однако если очень хочется, вам поможет следующее регулярное выражение:

```
a\sclass="link place-list__item-name"\shref=".+">(.+)<\/a>
```

Comment: регвыр не рабочий